# Computing the volume of a set efficiently

Tags: optimization

Given a set of vectors $\mathbf v_i$ for $i=1,\dots,k$, $\mathbf v_i \in \{0,1\}^n$, is that possible to efficiently find the volume of the set,

$$\left\{\mathbf x \in [0,1]^n:\mathbf x \le \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i\mathbf v_i\ \text{for some $\alpha_i$}\right\},$$
such that $\sum_i \alpha_i=1$ and $\alpha_i \ge 0$. The comparison $\mathbf x \le \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i\mathbf v_i$ is taken componentwise.

Note: the above question arose from [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176764/volume-of-n-dimensional-convex-hull) asked by me previously.

Comment: To all concerned: This is the union of the boxes $[0,x_1]\times[0,x_2]\times\cdots\times[0,x_n]$ for all $\mathbf x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ in the convex hull of the input vectors.

Comment: Perhaps more intuitively, it is the set of points dominated (in the sense of [Pareto efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency)) by said convex hull.

Comment: @Managu: Thanks for your comment. I don't know how to fix it either. Maybe it's not editable at all?

Answer (score 1):

I believe we can reduce the stated problem to your initial question about finding the volume of a convex polytope.

First, the set you describe, call it $A$ is convex.  In fact, we can specify a generating set for it.  For each 0-1 vector $\mathbf b\in\{0,1\}^n$, let $p_\mathbf b(\mathbf x)=(x_1\cdot b_1, x_2\cdot b_2,\ldots,x_n\cdot b_n)$.  That is, $p$ takes a vector $x$ and, in each place, replaces the coordinate with $0$ or leaves the coordinate alone, according to whether $b$ is $0$ or $1$. Then $A$ is the convex hull of $P=\left\{p_b(\mathbf{v}_i) : 0<i\leq k, \mathbf{b}\in \{0,1\}^n\right\}$.  Note that this set contains at most $k\cdot 2^n$ elements.

So we're back to, given a finite set, how do we calculate the volume of its convex hull?  A little reading around suggests that this is a hard problem.  See, e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/979/algorithm-for-finding-the-volume-of-a-convex-polytope.

Comment: Yes, the problem looks #P in general(http://www.renyi.hu/~miki/kopenwww.pdf). But I wonder, my problem, as a special case is hard as well?

Comment: Everything I've looked at suggests that really bad behavior tends to happen as the dimension goes up moreso than as the number of points goes up.  And a lot of the funky examples are given in the halfspace representation of a polytope, instead of the vertex representation as I'm discussing here.  If your dimension is fixed, I suspect the volume can be computed in time `poly(|V|)`.

Comment: Going in the other direction, the complex you describe subsumes the idea of the chain polytope of a poset, given in terms of the poset's maximal antichains.  Which, is #P to compute given just a description of the poset (it has the same volume as the order polytope which your link talks about).  But this doesn't prove hardness of your question -- a poset may have a number of maximal antichains exponential in its description size.